# Debugging what row is causing "Resources exceeded" error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

How does one debug Resources exceeded error messages from BigQuery, that are non-descript and do not point to any specific rows as causing the issue?

e.g.

```
bigquery error: Resources exceeded during query execution: ST_GeogFromGeoJSON failed: resources exhausted. Try simplifying the geometry.
```

I would love to simply/fix/remove the input to this function that's causing this issue, however, BigQuery doesn't give me ANY ideas as to how to debug this other than continuously re-query my dataset with different filters until I've eliminated the problematic row.

Any insights into how to debug these in the future would be much appreciated!

Or any BQ support engineers who can have the `SAFE` version of `ST_GeogFromGeoJSON` actually handle resource exceeding exceptions safely rather than throw this error message.

Reported the issue through [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203692294) as well.

Note: I also have this issue when trying to debug which rows are causing resources to be exceeded when using JS UDFs.

Edit:

An example query:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(decoded_line),
  ST_SIMPLIFY(SAFE.ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON(decoded_line), 30) AS simple_line
FROM polylines.decoded_lines
```

I'll try to find an example of a polyline that generates such an error, though...as I said above, it's been difficult to identify the exact one. Though I know this query works when down-sampling my dataset to 95% but excluding key timeframes.

Comment: JSON has no rows... while it complains about the complexity of the geometry. And this question also lacks the JSON (and eventually code) which produces the above error message.

Comment: While JSON has no rows, this is a common issue when debugging any query (where the results do have rows).

Updated above with query and more details.